# How to intercept a static resource request in angular

Tags: angular, authorization, angular-http-interceptors

In my angular app, I have the possibility to access server static resources (like images, documents, etc.) by an url like:
`http://localhost:4200/resources/logos/user_logo.png`.

In order to **protect the access to those resources**, I want to add an **authorization header** and pass a token into these requests so I can filter the access in my backend server.

This request to `/resources` is made outside the scope of my angular routes, I only have a proxy config redirecting the request directly to the backend target:

```json
{
  "/api": {
     ...
  },
  "/resources": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

At the same time, my authorization interceptor is not intercepting this type of requests (at least the log is not called), so currently I don't know how to solve this issue.

```js
...
@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log('intercept funtion called');
        
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${CookieHelper.getCookie('accessToken')}`,
                timestamp: '' + Date.now()
            }
        });

        return next.handle(request).pipe(...));
    }
}
```

My interceptor is being provided in AppModule like:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthorizationInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This part (prevent external access to files) is done by your web server and has nothing to do with angular

Comment: Yes @danvid, I'm aware of it. Just want a way of adding the access token into the requests.

Comment: "an usual angular interceptor wont intercept this type of requests" - can you make stackblitz sample please, i ve never seen such interceptor

Comment: I just put a sample of the interceptor code in the question ;)

Comment: thanks, it looks fine. You have one HttpClientModule imported in one place right, and the requests are being fired from the angular app, not a third-party library?

Comment: Yes, HttpClientModule imported in a single place. Regarding the requests, in this case the resource can be accessed directly by url and generally these requests are not called by an HttpClient request. From what I understood so far, only the requests done through HttpClient will be intercepted, which is not my case.
If, for instance, this resource requests were done by an url link in a html component (like an img), I could do a pipe and in some way add the authorization, but that is only a specific case of accessing a static resource, I would need a more generic approach...

Comment: @DavidR You are right about the requests for static resources not being executed by the Angular http client. Just to make sure, I added img and audio tags to my html, the requests show up in my browser's network tab but the interceptor doesn't intercept them.

Comment: @DavidR Did you get any solution for it yet?

Comment: @Himanshu I ended up re-implementing my authentication/authorization mechanism in a way that now I store my access token in a cookie, so it's automatically passed in every request.